# What is the range space of a homomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I am really confused about the intuitions of the range space of a homomorphism.

My textbook says the range space of a homomorphism $$h: V \to W\ is\ \ \mathscr{R}(h) = \{ h(\overrightarrow{v}) |\overrightarrow{v}\in V \}$$

sometimes denoted h(V). The dimension of the range space is the map's rank.

My understanding: the range space is all members of the V. But isn't V the domain? Then why is the range space referring to the range, which is W in this case? or is it the case that $h(\overrightarrow{v})$ is the image of the domain, so this makes it part of the codomain?

Thank you and apologize if any part of the question is confusing.

Comment: Do you understand how to read set builder notation?

Comment: Forget about linear map, just consider as a function and find it's range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the latter. The range space is the set of elements of $W$ which are of the form $h\left(\vec v\right)$ for some $\vec v\in V.$

For example, consider the map $h:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3$ given by $h\left([a,b]^T\right)=[a,a,a]^T.$ Geometrically speaking, the range of $h$ is the line through the origin consisting of all points whose coordinates are equal. This is not all of $W$ (which has dimension $3$), nor is it equal to $V$ (which has dimension $2$). The map $h$ has rank $1,$ since its range has dimension $1.$

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misreading the notation - specifically, you're missing the application of $h$: $$\mathscr{R}(h)=\{\color{red}{h(}\overrightarrow{v}\color{red}{)}\vert \overrightarrow{v}\in V\}.$$ If we omitted the bits in red we'd just be defining $V$, but including the bits in red means we're looking at **the things $h$ spits out when applied to** things in $V$, which is exactly what we want.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to understand by an example

Consider $\pi:\Bbb{R^2}\to \Bbb{R} $  defined by $\pi((x, y) )=x$ .

Your task to prove :

1. $\pi$ is a linear map.
2. $\pi$ is onto i.e $\mathscr{h}({\pi})=\Bbb{R}$

Can you see the difference?

Comment: I don’t see how OP will learn from point 2 since they don’t understand what the range is anyway.

Comment: I don't know what should be an appropriate reply to the your comment. I think one who studied linear map must know about an ordinary map between two sets and their range also from elementary set theory (which should be introduced much before than linear algebra in fact every linear algebra books start with some preliminary in set theory).Isn't it?